# How to use exists function in List. having error while searching an item in list in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, exists, datareader

I am creating a tree and I want to search if an NIC is present in the list or not but when I do `list.Exists(nic)` it gives error please help

```
List<PeopleInvolved> broList = new List<PeopleInvolved>();
List<PeopleInvolved> allInvolved = new List<PeopleInvolved>();
string value = "null";

foreach (var person in allInvolved)
{
    conn.Open();
    nic = person.NIC;
    using (dr3 = cmd5.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (!dr3.Read())
        {
            dr3.Close();

            if (broList.Exists(nic))
            {
                valueTable.Add(nic, 6);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the error occurs in the following line
if (brolist.Exists(nic))
a red line is shown under "(nic)"

Comment: Where are the definitions of `broList` and `nic`?

Comment: `List<PeopleInvolved> broList = new List<PeopleInvolved>();`

`string nic = "null";`

Comment: this is my first tym on stackoverflow so dont know the rules to post. sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question misses a lot of information, I think what you need is:

```
if (broList.Exists(p=>p.NIC==nic))
```